# Apache2 on Ubuntu 12.04: mysqlnd+mysqli and pdo_mysql - can i have both?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, mysqli, apache2

I have a strange error. If I install php5-mysqlnd, i can use mysqli and its functions. But i get a warning at startup in /var/apache2/error.log

[image]

If I install php5-mysql, i cannot use mysqli anymore, it won't load anymore. So i need to remove php5-mysql and invoke `apt-get --reinstall install php5-mysqlnd` to make mysqli work again. And I am getting this warning again.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PEAR to install PHP modules. Try `sudo pecl install pdo_cubrid`. If `pecl` isn't installed - `sudo apt-get install -y php-pear php5-dev`. This will install PEAR and PHP 5 headers for module compilation.